# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1.01^n = +\infty$

Tags: limits

Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1.01^n = +\infty$

It seems simple enough however it is giving me problems, any help?

Comment: This simply isn't true: $1.01^n \geq 1 + \frac{n}{100}$, which has limit $+\infty$.

Comment: ok so how would prove that it goes to infinity?

Comment: The comment about just proved it for you!

Comment: @Pasie15, can you write down the definition of what it means that the limit is infinity?

Answer (score 3):

Any number above one, as its power increases, increases, and as the power goes to infinity, the number will go to infinity.

Just a few cases to show how it expands (calculated in WolframAlpha)

$1.01^{10} \approx 1.1046 $

$1.01^{100} \approx 2.7048 $

$1.01^{1000} \approx 20959.15563 $

$1.01^{10000} \approx 1.635*10^{43} $

As you can see, it rapidly goes to infinity, like any other exponential function above 1.

The proof that relies on proof rather than data is actually quite simple. its just that $1.01^n\ge1+\frac{n}{100}$ (proof for this shown below), and that $1+\frac{n}{100}$ goes to infinity as n goes to infinity, so anything bigger than it must also go to infinity as n goes to infinity.

$$1.01^n=(\frac{101}{100})^n=(1+\frac{1}{100})^n$$
By the binomial theorem, every time the power increases, the first term will be $1$, and the second term will be $n*1*\frac{1}{100}$, and all other terms have to be positive,so when added together, the first two terms are $1+\frac{n}{100}$ and all other terms will only make it larger, so $1.01^n\ge1+\frac{n}{100}$

Comment: ok thank you, my mistake

Comment: Aw, come on. An unexplained downvote? I can live with downvotes. Just tell me what is wrong, and how I can help clear up the issue.

Comment: Shouldn't you prove that $1.01^n>1+\frac n{100}$ ?

Comment: Good point, although somewhat simple in my mind, I should show it. Give me a minute or two to do so.

Comment: Also, I realized that it has to be greater than or equal to, not just greater than. The equal case occurs at n=1 and n=2

Answer (score 2):

For all $a>1$ we have 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a^n=+\infty$$
In fact

$$\log (a^n)=n\log a\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}+\infty$$

Comment: The second limit works for all cases a>1. For a=1, then you get 0, if 0<a<1 then it approaches negaitve infinity

Comment: This answer assumes that $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^x = \infty$.

Comment: Yeah, you have to put some limits on a before you can make a broad statement like that

Answer (score 1):

Use the inequality
$$
(1+\delta)^n \geqslant 1+n\delta,
$$
valid for $\delta>0$. Now let $n \to +\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know Bernoulli's inequality $(1+x)^n\geq 1+xn$ for $x\geq-1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then
$$
(1+0.01)^n\geq 1+\frac{n}{100}\to+\infty\text{ as }n\to\infty.
$$
The inequality itself can be proved by an elementary induction argument.